# How to change to home directory using "cd" and a relative path?

Tags: cd-command, home

I am doing an assignment that requires me to change in to my home directory from my current directory which is `~/sample_dir1/sample_dir/cambridge`.

It asks me to change to my home directory **using a relative pathname** and **not** using `cd` by itself, with no arguments.

I have tried numerous combinations of `cd ~/` and `cd ..` etc., but nothing seems to work.

Comment: One of your classmates asked a very similar question [10 days ago](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261943)...

Comment: and there was no answer?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried (you did this), and what the result was. I suspect that if you were to add this to you question, then you would not press submit, as you could figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

in your directory, if you do `ls -a` it will list all subdirectories, including the two special directories: `.` and `..`

`.` refers to the current directory.

`..` refers to the parent of the current directory.

Therefore `cd ..` brings you up one level.

`cd ../../..` brings you up 3 levels, which should take you to home.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out the relative path from the current directory to some other directory, you may use the GNU tool `realpath` with its `--relative-to` option.

For example, I'm currently in `/home/myself/Work/Development/project01/scripts` and I want to find the relative path to my home directory, `/home/myself`:

```
$ realpath --relative-to=. ~
../../../..
```

The command I used here calculates the relative path from `.`, the current directory, to `~`, my home directory.

I would then be able to use `cd ../../../..` to end up in my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

below two will point to home directory only.

```
cd ~
```

OR

```
 cd
```

Relative path movement can be done using

```
cd ../../..
```

you can move to previous directory using

```
cd -
```

Comment: Ive tried both "cd ~"  and "cd" is not allowed

Comment: if it is relative path, you can use cd ../../.. etc

Comment: @user157961, I suggest you to select Liam answer.

Comment: @Liam, you beat me bro